# wordpress sql error in one page ( my account)

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress

[image: error in "my account " page only]

I installed a theme " directorypress" to my wordpress site, all woks fine except when I click my account page I get this error.
did any one go through this issue before

### wordpress version 4.2.2

pages attached to the following link 
[pages in the error](https://www.dropbox.com/s/hzhm6xdl4dxbtcy/pages.rar?dl=0)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change the following lines

```
$result = mysql_query($SQL, $wpdb->dbh) or die(mysql_error().' on line: '.__LINE__);
$result = mysql_query($wpdb->dbh,$SQL) or die(mysql_error().' on line: '.__LINE__);
```

and use `mysqli`

Comment: Why all pages work fine if the connection is not correct.

Comment: in header file i think put satic database connection so that why its not properly work.please check it

Comment: Thank you, I'll check,I'm using mysql not mysqli, if that may help identified the problem

Comment: other wise in that page cant get database connection so it will

Comment: sorry, I couldn't find anything related to what you say :(

Comment: check in my account.php in line number 249

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/82093/discussion-between-armia-and-anilviradiya).